# JUnit: testing if-else statements

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I'm testing the following method:

```
private String getHomeStateCountry(Details aDetails, String aCountry) {
    String homeState = Constants.BLANK_SPACE;
    if (Constants.USA.equalsIgnoreCase((aCountry))) {
        if (aDetails.getStateCountry() != null) {
            homeState = aDetails.getStateCountry().getStateName();
        }
    } else {
        if (aDetails.getStateCountry() != null) {
            homeState = aDetails.getStateCountry().getCountryName();
        }
    }
    return homeState;
}
```

When writing JUnits for this method, Is it pointless to set the stateName and countryName for each test(so if something goes wrong, e.g. the state is returned instead of the country, then the fail message provides a more accurate explanation etc) or should each test only set the value under test, i.e. if I'm testing for other than USA, only set countryName and check the returned value?

Comment: what you try to achieve? it's not clear here, you want to test method properly, don't u?

Comment: Well I am admittedly largely clueless about JUnit and unit testing, I want to make sure each branch in the if statement is tested, as well as testing the returned value if the stateCountry is null for both Constant.USA and other

Comment: so, what's your question? if you want to test each branch - just do it, don't see any blockers here

Comment: There are no blockers, I'm just curious about whether both countryName and stateName should be set for both branches of the if else when writing JUnits for the sake of a detailed error message should something result in the execution of the wrong path(e.g. a constant is changed by someone) or is it sufficient to set only the field under test

Comment: In this particular case I would probably write one test case to test when aCountry was USA (that would be calls where the value is passed in as both "USA" and "usa", a second test when aCountry is a random string and a third case when aCountry were null. Inside each test you can verify multiple getHomeStateCountry() calls.

Comment: Ah I see, initially i had planned to write 5; 2 for USA with stateCountry ==null && != null, 2 of the same for anything other than USA and 1 with aCountry as null with both countryName and stateName populated

Comment: Apologies, it is, correcting question

Comment: It's not an exact science. One huge test probably isn't all that useful. To write 20 tests for such a simple method is probably overkill. As you write more and more unit tests and see how they play out over time you'll get a better feel for how much you want to do for each test case. Another good benchmark is bugs. If someone ever found a bug in this code, write a test case that fails because of the bug and when you fix the bug the test will go green. Over time you'll be happy you did it.